# Create a basic calculator with (+,-,*,/) including the 'IsDigit' function to determine whether the input is a number or not

Tags: calculator

I just started my career, I am very novice, but I have to make a basic calculator that (+,-,*,/), but in the calculator must exist the function "Esdigit", to determine if the entered data is a number or not.
data entered is a number or not. The function returns true if the input is a number, and returns true if the input is a number.
is a number, and returns false if the input is not a number.

What I don't know is how to implement this function after reading the value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA9tF.png)

I tried to do it this way, but I had to modify the name of the function, besides I don't know if this way the validation is good.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please specify the programming language. I believe your mention of "basic calculator" might not at all mean this question is about the BASIC programming language. And even if it is about BASIC, then you would still have to specify which dialect.

Comment: Welcome! It's important that you show your work with relevant details (code, sample inputs, expected vs actual behavior, errors, etc). You can't just post a set of requirements and then ask the Community to solve it for you, without showing any effort of your own (well you *can* but this typically leads to downvotes, closure, and deletion fairly quickly)

Comment: Also: the [tag:basic] tag is for a programming language, and explicitly says "DO NOT USE TO INDICATE YOUR QUESTION IS SIMPLE!" in the tag description. I removed this (and other) tags, they are not relevant to your question

Answer (score -1):

In JS you can write function like this

```js
function isDigit(input) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(input)) && isFinite(input);
}

console.log(isDigit(1))
```

Comment: The OP hasn't shown any code at all, and they haven't even specified a programming language. So... you're not answering any question; you're just writing your own code to solve their assignment. Please don't do this.